# Xamarin C# how do i add interface or class to AppDelegate?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Sample Code as project is available here: [Github Project file](https://github.com/shamun/xamarin-ios/tree/master/ios-interface)

How do i add my EmptyInterface or EmptyClass in AppDelegate? When i apply `public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate, EmptyInterface or public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate, EmptyClass` it fails

Can anyone please show me the correct way please?

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace testing {

  [Register("AppDelegate")]

  public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate {

    public override UIWindow Window {
      get;
      set;
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** The error code:

> AppDelegate.cs(53,53): Error CS0535: 'AppDelegate' does not implement interface member 'EmptyInterface.EmptyInterfaceMethod1()' (CS0535) (testing)
>
> or
>
> AppDelegate.cs(53,53): Error CS1721: Class 'AppDelegate' cannot have multiple base classes: 'UIApplicationDelegate' and 'EmptyClass' (CS1721) (testing)

Comment: What do you mean it fails? What error does it give?

Comment: Class is surely not valid, You can inherit just from one class which is `UIApplicationDelegate` at this time. But You should be still able to implement an interface. What is the failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code is valid, because You have not completed the code in proper way:

1. **Interface**:

   > `AppDelegate` does not implement interface member `EmptyInterface.EmptyInterfaceMethod1()`

This one tells You that there is existing interface called `EmptyInterface` which have method `EmptyInterfaceMethod1`, and You have to implement that (use) in Your code.

Solution:

```
interface IEmptyInterface {

    int EmptyInterfaceMethod1();

}

public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate, IEmptyInterface {

    public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }

    //The type and parameter have to be same as in the interface!
    public int EmptyInterfaceMethod1() { return 1; }

}
```

**Note** that common approach is name interface with capital **I** at the start of the name. Correct name would be `IEmptyInterface` in Your case.

---

2. **Class**

> Class `AppDelegate` cannot have multiple base classes: `UIApplicationDelegate` and `EmptyClass`

This one is pretty straight-forward, You **can't** have a class (`AppDelegate`), that inherits from 2 base classes. This is something that language syntax of C# not supporting. Because then there would be issue like same-named properties or methods, etc..

Comment: @YumYumYum Go through the errors Yourself and try to figure out, what they mean. It is pretty straight-forward. `The namespace 'testing' already contains a definition for 'EmptyInterface'` Means You have 2 times defined interface in same namespace.

Comment: Now its working after applying your last EDIT. Thanks!! updates are commited here: https://github.com/shamun/xamarin-ios/blob/master/ios-interface/testing/AppDelegate.cs